# Select a maximum of 2 rows where a column has the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a maximum of 2 rows where a column has the same value. ie:

```
id  title   accountid   date
1   job 1       1      Oct. 1
2   job 2       1      Oct. 1
3   job 3       1      Oct. 1
4   job 1       2      Oct. 2
5   job a       3      Oct. 2
6   job z       4      Oct. 3
7   job 2       2      Oct. 3
8   job 3       2      Oct. 8
```

I want to select

```
    1   job 1       1      Oct. 1
    2   job 2       1      Oct. 1
                                   <----- Skip this row because we already 
                                          have 2 from account 1
    4   job 1       2      Oct. 2
    5   job a       3      Oct. 2
    6   job z       4      Oct. 3
    7   job 2       2      Oct. 3
```

What I'm using right now to select is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY date DESC, RAND()
```

I've looked a bit into using `HAVING COUNT(accountid) <= 2` but that's just led to confusion. I'm pretty new to using sql.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

Hi, thanks for all the quick responses. I've tried each of them and couldn't seem to get them to work. I figured out a way to limit the jobs per account id using php. Thanks again for your time and efforts to help me solve this.

Comment: that is a really good question...

Comment: What you ideally want is windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()`. Unfortunately for you, mysql doesn't support them. Try searching for implementations of them in Mysql

Comment: I hope you didn't actually name a table "**table**".  Don't name things using SQL reserve words.

Comment: @MarlinPierce haha of course I didn't :P This is just a very brief example.

Answer (score 2):

```
set @id := 0, @acid := 0;
select t.id, title, accountid, `date`
from 
    t
    inner join (
        select 
            id, 
            if(@acid = accountid, @i := @i + 1, @i := 1) as i,
            @acid := accountid as acid
        from t
        order by accountid, `date` desc
    ) s on t.id = s.id
where s.i <= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi this gonna solve your problem, but I don't know how quick this query will be.

**[SQLFIDDLE example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08950/39)**

QUERY:

```
SELECT
id, 
title,
accountid,
date
FROM
    (SELECT
     IF(@prev != a.accountid, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, 
     @prev:=a.accountid, 
     a.*
     FROM (
           SELECT 
           t1.id, 
           t1.title,
           t1.accountid,
           t1.date
           FROM tbl t1,
           (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev:='') sq
              ORDER BY  accountid, id) a
    )b
WHERE b.rownumber<3
ORDER BY b.id
```

Result:

```
| ID | TITLE | ACCOUNTID |   DATE |
-----------------------------------
|  1 | job 1 |         1 | Oct. 1 |
|  2 | job 2 |         1 | Oct. 1 |
|  4 | job 1 |         2 | Oct. 2 |
|  5 | job a |         3 | Oct. 2 |
|  6 | job z |         4 | Oct. 3 |
|  7 | job 2 |         2 | Oct. 3 |
```

Comment: A couple of timesaving SQL Fiddle tips: you can copy OP's sample data and paste it into the "Text to DDL" tool as a simple means of quickly building your table (much faster than manually doing so).  Here's your exact query running against the schema I built doing just that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9efe/1  Also, you can change the output to "plaintext" (dropdown arrow next to Run SQL button) and that makes for an easier format to paste into your answer, here.  Cheers!

Comment: I believe you misunderstood me a bit here. I don't want more than 2 rows with the same _accountid_ not _date_ I'm just going to assume that the difference would be grouping by and selecting accountid in the lowest level subquery.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand, check now. Select only two first rows with same accountID? I updated and sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tab.id, tab.title, tab.accountid, tab.date
FROM table tab INNER JOIN table count_tab ON tab.id = count_tab.id
WHERE count_tab.id <= tab.id
GROUP BY tab.id, tab.title, tab.accountid, tab.date
HAVING count(count_tab.id) <= 2
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think because you are grouping by only one column and don't have any aggregate functions. But again I'm new to SQL and the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are confusing to me.

Comment: This has been an area of difficulty.  Different DB vendor's SQL dialects work differently.  I edited my answer for what would work for DB2.  However, it might not work for mysql, instead you would need my original answer.